# BERT: Unable to reproduce sentence-to-embedding operation

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to convert sentence to embedding, with the following code.

```
import torch
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertForMaskedLM

model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

text = "[CLS] This is a sentence. [SEP]"
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
input_ids = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.tokenize(text))])
encoded_layers, pooled_output = model(input_ids, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
```

The code worked. However, each time I run this code, it gives a different result. `encoded_layers` and `pooled_output` changes every time, for the same input.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe "dropout" works while inferencing. You can try model.eval()

In addition, "transformers" is Long-Time-Support. Stop using pytorch_pretrained_bert

```py
import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertModel

bert_path = "/Users/Caleb/Desktop/codes/ptms/bert-base"
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(bert_path)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(bert_path)

max_length = 32
test_str = "This is a sentence."
tokenized = tokenizer(test_str, max_length=max_length, padding="max_length")
input_ids = tokenized['input_ids']
input_ids = torch.unsqueeze(torch.LongTensor(input_ids), 0)
attention_mask = tokenized['attention_mask']
attention_mask = torch.unsqueeze(torch.IntTensor(attention_mask), 0)
res = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
print(res.last_hidden_state)
```

Comment: "transformers" is Long-Time-Support. Stop using pytorch_pretrained_bert